# Query about CSV File Conversion into another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, csv

This is a working program for conversion of CSV file into tabled excel file. My question is how can this be modified and order the program to process the csv file into another workbook bec. in the codes below, the code processes the csv file into Sheet2. Thank you

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportFile()
Dim sPath As String
Dim intChoice As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim FilePath As String

'change the display name of the open file dialog
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Title = _
    "CSV File Opener"

'Remove all other filters
Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Clear

'Add a custom filter
Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Add( _
    "CSV Files Only", "*.csv")

'only allow the user to select one file
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False

'make the file dialog visible to the user
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

If intChoice <> 0 Then

    'get the file path selected by the user
    strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
        msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

    Cells(7, 7) = strPath
Else
    MsgBox "Wrong CSV File. Please Choose Again"

End If
'Below we assume that the file, csvtest.csv,
'is in the same folder as the workbook. If
'you want something more flexible, you can
'use Application.GetOpenFilename to get a
'file open dialogue that returns the name
'of the selected file.
'On the page Fast text file import
'I show how to do that - just replace the
'file pattern "txt" with "csv".
sPath = strPath

'Procedure call. Semicolon is defined as separator,
'and data is to be inserted on "Sheet2".
'Of course you could also read the separator
'and sheet name from the worksheet or an input
'box. There are several options.
copyDataFromCsvFileToSheet sPath, ";", "Sheet2"

End Sub
'**************************************************************
Private Sub copyDataFromCsvFileToSheet(parFileName As String, _
parDelimiter As String, parSheetName As String)

Dim Data As Variant  'Array for the file values

'Function call - the file is read into the array
Data = getDataFromFile(parFileName, parDelimiter)

'If the array isn't empty it is inserted into
'the sheet in one swift operation.
If Not isArrayEmpty(Data) Then
  'If you want to operate directly on the array,
  'you can leave out the following lines.
  With Sheets(parSheetName)
    'Delete any old content
    .Cells.ClearContents
    'A range gets the same dimensions as the array
    'and the array values are inserted in one operation.
    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)) = Data
  End With
End If

End Sub

    Public Function isArrayEmpty(parArray As Variant) As Boolean
'Returns False if not an array or a dynamic array
'that hasn't been initialised (ReDim) or
'deleted (Erase).

If IsArray(parArray) = False Then isArrayEmpty = True
On Error Resume Next
If UBound(parArray) < LBound(parArray) Then
   isArrayEmpty = True
   Exit Function
Else
   isArrayEmpty = False
End If

End Function
'**************************************************************
Private Function getDataFromFile(parFileName As String, _
parDelimiter As String, _
Optional parExcludeCharacter As String = "") As Variant
'parFileName is the delimited file (csv, txt ...)
'parDelimiter is the separator, e.g. semicolon.
'The function returns an empty array, if the file
'is empty or cannot be opened.
'Number of columns is based on the line with most
'columns and not the first line.
'parExcludeCharacter: Some csv files have strings in
'quotations marks ("ABC"), and if parExcludeCharacter = """"
'quotation marks are removed.

Dim locLinesList() As Variant 'Array
Dim locData As Variant        'Array
Dim i As Long                 'Counter
Dim j As Long                 'Counter
Dim locNumRows As Long        'Nb of rows
Dim locNumCols As Long        'Nb of columns
Dim fso As Variant            'File system object
Dim ts As Variant             'File variable
Const REDIM_STEP = 10000      'Constant

'If this fails you need to reference Microsoft Scripting Runtime.
'You select this in "Tools" (VBA editor menu).
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

On Error GoTo error_open_file
'Sets ts = the file
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(parFileName)
On Error GoTo unhandled_error

'Initialise the array
ReDim locLinesList(1 To 1) As Variant
i = 0
'Loops through the file, counts the number of lines (rows)
'and finds the highest number of columns.
Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
  'If the row number Mod 10000 = 0
  'we redimension the array.
  If i Mod REDIM_STEP = 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve locLinesList _
    (1 To UBound(locLinesList, 1) + REDIM_STEP) As Variant
  End If
  locLinesList(i + 1) = Split(ts.ReadLine, parDelimiter)
  j = UBound(locLinesList(i + 1), 1) 'Nb of columns in present row
  'If the number of columns is then highest so far.
  'the new number is saved.
  If locNumCols < j Then locNumCols = j
  i = i + 1
Loop

ts.Close 'Close file

locNumRows = i

'If number of rows is zero
If locNumRows = 0 Then Exit Function

ReDim locData(1 To locNumRows, 1 To locNumCols + 1) As Variant

'Copies the file values into an array.
'If parExcludeCharacter has a value,
'the characters are removed.
If parExcludeCharacter <> "" Then
  For i = 1 To locNumRows
    For j = 0 To UBound(locLinesList(i), 1)
      If Left(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
        If Right(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
          locLinesList(i)(j) = _
          Mid(locLinesList(i)(j), 2, Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 2)
        Else
          locLinesList(i)(j) = _
          Right(locLinesList(i)(j), Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 1)
        End If
      ElseIf Right(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
        locLinesList(i)(j) = _
        Left(locLinesList(i)(j), Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 1)
      End If
      locData(i, j + 1) = locLinesList(i)(j)
    Next j
  Next i
Else
  For i = 1 To locNumRows
    For j = 0 To UBound(locLinesList(i), 1)
      locData(i, j + 1) = locLinesList(i)(j)
    Next j
  Next i
End If

getDataFromFile = locData

Exit Function

error_open_file:  'Returns empty Variant
unhandled_error:  'Returns empty Variant

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Again, sorry, no Excel here at home.  The problem is copyDataFromCsvFileToSheet.  It needs to be re-written to either create a workbook with worksheets or to accept a workbook with worksheets as a parameter.  What it was doing was just saving to the current workbook.  Try changing this part:

```
'Procedure call. Semicolon is defined as separator,
'and data is to be inserted on "Sheet2".
'Of course you could also read the separator
'and sheet name from the worksheet or an input
'box. There are several options.

'create a workbook object
dim wb as workbook
'create a new workbook
set wb = workbooks.add
copyDataFromCsvFileToSheet sPath, ";", wb
set wb = nothing

End Sub
'**************************************************************
Private Sub copyDataFromCsvFileToSheet(parFileName As String, _
parDelimiter As String, wb as workbook)

Dim Data As Variant  'Array for the file values

'Function call - the file is read into the array
Data = getDataFromFile(parFileName, parDelimiter)

'If the array isn't empty it is inserted into
'the sheet in one swift operation.
If Not isArrayEmpty(Data) Then
  'If you want to operate directly on the array,
  'you can leave out the following lines.
  With wb.worksheets("Sheet1")
    'Delete any old content
    .Cells.ClearContents
    'A range gets the same dimensions as the array
    'and the array values are inserted in one operation.
    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)) = Data
    wb.saveas Filename:="whateveryouwant.xlsx"
  End With
End If



End Sub
```

Comment: There is a msgbox saying that "Type Mismatch" with this code:
copyDataFromCsvFileToSheet sPath, ";", "Sheet2" then higlights the "Sheet2" portion. Thank you.